# Error connecting to API but able to connect when running unit test in C#

Tags: c#, .net, api

I am trying to build a service that connects from a Web API using HttpClient class. The service runs okay under unit tests but encounters an error when I call the service from a controller. Here's the code for my service

```
public List<Recipe> FindRecipe(string searchTerm)
{
    List<Recipe> result = null;
    string apiPath = BuiltApiPath(searchTerm);
    var task = AppHttpClient.Instance().
        GetAsync(new Uri(apiPath))
        .ContinueWith((taskReponse) =>
        {
            var response = taskReponse.Result;
            var jsonString = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            jsonString.Wait();
            dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(jsonString.Result);
            result = ((IEnumerable)data.hits).Cast<dynamic>().
                Select(h => new Recipe { Name = h.recipe.label, ImageUrl = h.recipe.image, Uri = h.recipe.uri }).
                ToList();
        });
    task.Wait();
    return result;
}
```

And here's the exception I'm getting

```
Exception information: 
    Exception type: AggregateException 
    Exception message: One or more errors occurred.
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()
   at RecipeFinder.Services.RecipeService.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<FindRecipe>b__0(Task`1 taskReponse) in \\dtchyb-mnmh001\c_wfp_users\u595357\my documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\RecipeFinder\RecipeFinder\Services\RecipeService.cs:line 24
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationTaskFromResultTask`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()

An error occurred while sending the request.

Unable to connect to the remote server
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult ar)

A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 107.20.173.119:443
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception)
```

Comment: This might be a stupid question, but does your unit test actually call the API, or a mock?

Comment: The unit test calls the service directly

Comment: And you're 100% positive it's calling exactly the same address? Because that looks like an error indicating the service isn't actually listening at the address you're trying to access. Is it on a remote machine in both cases (unit test and live)?

Comment: 100% positive that it's the same address. Both are running on my local machine.

Comment: @RichardPadre Probably a context issue where you are ending up in a deadlock. You seem to be mixing async and blocking calls. as HttpClient is primarily an async API

Comment: Which specific context does HttpClient could be having a deadlock?